# Image changes back after selecting size swatch

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, swatches, color-swatches

I am experiencing the following issue with swatches;

I have 3 swatches: Colour, Size, Length. I have set up the colour swatch to change to the photo related to it but whenever I select a size/length after that, the image will change back to the initial photo. Is there any way to prevent this, so the image stays the same?

An example can be found here; http://www.neflyx-webshop.com/nieuweshop/index.php/dames/dream/mac-broek-dream-skinny-authentic.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add an image to each and every simple product that is related to the configurable product. Every simple product should have its own image. Also verify that each of those images is set as the base image for this simple product.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Is it possible to have a product use the image of another simple product? Since I now have to upload the same image for each and every combination of size and length?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with my site. I am using [tzyganu/switcher](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher) to solve the problem. It works fine with the rwd theme.

It has a feature to limit image switching to specific attributes. In our case color. See [`Change images when these attributes are changed`](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/wiki/configuration)

The only downside I see for it is it will not place the swatches on the category page.

Answer (score 0):

I' ve had the same problem and i don't want to set every image. I need to reload the product image just for the color attribute so i change the updateSelect() function on the file "**/js/skin/frontend/THEME/default/configurableswatches/**swatches-product.js" (line **725**) and add this :

```
   if (attr._e.selectedOption !== false && attr._e.optionSelect && (attr.code == 'color')) {
```

This way magento will reload the image only when you select a color swatch.

Hope it helps!