# when i click on color swatch in list page then same image not shown at product page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, color-swatches

when I click on color swatch in list page then same image not shown at product page in magento 2.

after click on swatch image changed at list page but click on this image then open the product page but not loading same image which i have click.

what should i have do?

Comment: Make sure to add an image to each and every simple product that is related to the configurable product. Every simple product should have its own image. Also verify that each of those images is set as the base image for this simple product. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/48739/82670

Comment: i have uploaded base image each of those. so every simple product have its own image but after click on swatch base image of selected swatch not showing at product page.